# How to POST/PUT array param in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parameters

My controller methods work great for my ERB forms, but aren't accepting arrays as JSON parameters.  I have an array of ids called "style_ids" that gets stripped out from JSON.

Permitted parameters:

```
params.require(:beer).permit(:name, :brewery_id, :style_ids => [])
```

When posted from ***ERB***, it looks like this:

```
all params: {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>”…”, "beer"=>{"name"=>"Amber", "style_ids"=>["", "1"], "brewery_id"=>"16"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"beers", "id"=>"213"}
permitted params: {"name"=>"Amber", "brewery_id"=>"16", "style_ids"=>["", "1"]}
```

When I submit via ***JSON*** though, it looks like this:

```
params: {"id"=>"213", "name"=>"Amber", "style_ids"=>["1", "22"], "brewery_id"=>16, "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"beers", "beer"=>{"id"=>213, "name"=>"Amber", "brewery_id"=>16}}
Unpermitted parameters: id
permitted params: {"name"=>"Amber", "brewery_id"=>16}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with Rails showing style_ids inside the beer hash in my regular request.  What am I doing wrong that's keeping this from showing up in my JSON request?  The JSON is really simple: `{"id":213,"name":"Amber","style_ids":["1","22"],"brewery_id":16}`

I've already read a lot of documentation about this and feel like I'm doing it the right way...hopefully I'm just missing something.  Thanks!

Comment: hi Dennis, where is your controller permit parameters action?

Comment: Actually that should be inside `beer`. See what you have written on controller is `params.require(:beer)` which means the params hash has a key named `beer` and the attributes to permit are inside it. In your `JSON` request you have this: `"beer"=>{"id"=>213, "name"=>"Amber", "brewery_id"=>16}` from which `id` is not permitted so it is showing `Unpermitted parameters: id`. Of the rest it don't cares whatever you are sending. Because rails will use the attributes inside `beer` to create/update it.

Comment: So why isn't style_ids inside of the beer hash when using JSON?  Rails considers the other arguments inside that hash, but not style_ids.  
@huanson, I'm not sure I follow...  the entire permit parameters is inside a function: 

```def beer_params
  params.require(:beer).permit(:name, :brewery_id, :style_ids => [])
end```

I call this from my update and create functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out this out.  Rails is using `wrap_parameters` so I can use `{“name": “name”}` instead of `{“beer:{“name” : “name”}}`.  by default Rails wraps anything from your model’s `attribute_names`.

My problem was `style_ids` is an external join table (`has_and_belongs_to_many`), so that’s not in the `attribute_names`.  I fixed this by adding this to the top of my controller:  `wrap_parameters :beer, include: [:style_ids, :name, :brewery_id]`

The link that finally got me through this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html